# Why doesn't checking if the reverse of a string equals that string in rust

Tags: rust

my approach to checking if x is palindrome is to convert x to a string(thing), slice it and reverse it, then compare if reversed thing and thing are equal. Compiler throws this error.

```
Line 8, Char 27: cannot move out of `thing` because it is borrowed (solution.rs)
  |
8 |       if thing == reverse(thing) {
  |          -----            ^^^^^ move out of `thing` occurs here
  |          |
  |          borrow of `thing` occurs here
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0505`.
error: could not compile `prog` due to previous error
mv: cannot stat '/leetcode/rust_compile/target/release/prog': No such file or directory
```

```rust
fn reverse(s: String) -> String {
    s.chars().rev().collect()
}
impl Solution {
    pub fn is_palindrome(x: i32) -> bool {
        let thing: String;
        thing = x.to_string();
        if thing == reverse(thing) {
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is missing something in the title. "Why doesn't [subject]" *do what*?

Answer (score 3):

Like the compiler tells you, you try to move `thing` while it is borrowed.
It can be easily fixed here by having `reverse` take a reference:

```rust
fn reverse(s: &str) -> String {
    s.chars().rev().collect()
}
impl Solution {
    pub fn is_palindrome(x: i32) -> bool {
        let thing: String;
        thing = x.to_string();
        if thing == reverse(&thing) {
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
}
```

In the book the [chapter on ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) explains this in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in ownership, i.e. deciding whether to provide a value (by moving it) or to provide a reference, here is a slightly different approach.

In your attempt, you decided to build a second string based on the first one (consuming the first one by the way, this is the reason of the error).
This second string is an entirely new value, with a newly allocated storage for the chars in reverse order.

The example below uses only references in order to visit the bytes of the first (and only) string and compare them starting from both ends.
Because the string contains only digits, we assume comparing bytes is equivalent to comparing chars in this specific problem.

`bytes.iter()` iterates forward and `bytes.iter().rev()` iterates backward; both within the same string designated by references (these two iterators reference the string).
These two sequences are combined with `.zip()` in order to generate pairs of bytes.
Because of this specific problem, we do not need to iterate till the end, half the length is enough to decide, then we only `.take()` half the length of this sequence of pairs.
Finally, `.all()` these pairs of bytes (till the half) must contain the two same bytes.

Whatever the algorithm here, the idea is to illustrate that with references we don't have necessarily to build new values.

```rust
fn is_palindrome(x: i32) -> bool {
    let text = x.to_string();
    let bytes = text.as_bytes(); // bytes are ASCII chars here (digits)
    let half_len = bytes.len() / 2;
    let forward_bytes = bytes.iter();
    let backward_bytes = bytes.iter().rev();
    forward_bytes
        .zip(backward_bytes)
        .take(half_len)
        .all(|(a, b)| a == b)
}
fn main() {
    for n in [1232, 12321, 123321] {
        println!("{} ~~> {}", n, is_palindrome(n))
    }
}
/*
1232 ~~> false
12321 ~~> true
123321 ~~> true
*/
```

Comment: For completeness sake, note that `text.len()` is the length of the string in **bytes** not chars, so your function may still do more comparisons than strictly necessary in the presence of multi-byte chars. OTOH there is no easy way to get the length in chars (other than iterating through the full string which kind of defeats the purpose), so getting to a fully optimal solution is pretty complicated.

Comment: @Jmb I agree with you in the general case (multi-byte chars). However, I think in this specific example, the string contains only decimal ascii chars (à la `isdigit()`) then bytes and chars will be equivalent.

Comment: I had missed that the input was a number. In that case, it would make sense (and probably be faster and be more explicit) to use [`bytes()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.bytes) instead of `chars()` since `bytes()` won't try to decode the UTF-8 characters.