# how to reverse a list without moving in rust

Tags: rust, reverse, borrow-checker

I'm trying to write a simple function to detect palindromes. I couldn't find a way to avoid moving nums while reversing it, so I ended up with the following:

```
fn is_palindrome(num: String) -> bool {
    let nums: Vec<char> = num.chars().collect();  
    let reversed: Vec<char> = nums.clone().into_iter().rev().collect();  
    nums == reversed         
}
```

Is there a way to do this without having to use .clone()? Thanks.

Comment: Since `char: Copy` you can do `nums.iter().copied().rev().collect()`. You should also probably make `num: &str` because you don't need ownership to get the chars out.

Comment: It's worth noting you might not actually have to `collect()` here, you could compare `next()` vs. `next()` on the forward vs. reverse iterators of the same thing and if they ever differ, halt.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75761465/5397009

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you don't need to collect either the forward or reverse iteration into a vec. In fact you don't even need to consume the input string.

Instead you can just create a forward iterator, and a reverse iterator, and compare them using the [Iterator::eq](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.eq) method:

```rust
fn is_palindrome(num: &str) -> bool {
    num.chars().eq(num.chars().rev())
}
```

Comment: I think this is doing two full traversals, but only one traversal is really necessary, which should be easy to fix by using `take(num.len()/2)`.

Comment: @hkBst `num.len()` gives the number of bytes, not the number of chars. I had a previous version that did something similar but counted the number of chars, and someone did a benchmark and found it was actually slower. Check the previous versions of this answer.

Comment: You are right of course. It is also true that the number of chars is not more than the number of bytes, so this can still be used to get a conservative estimate for the maximum number of chars, without actually counting them (which would require a full traversal of its own, negating any benefits).

Answer (score 1):

While @harmic's version is quite readable you can avoid traversing the string twice (without all the pitfalls of `take`, and `num.len()` vs `num.chars().count()`, ...) by using the `DoubleEndedIterator` implementation of `Chars` unfortunately that means we can't use the pretty `Iterator::eq` any longer:

```rust
fn is_palindrome(num: &str) -> bool {
    let mut it = s.chars();
    while let (Some(a), Some(b)) = (it.next(), it.next_back()) {
        if a != b {
            return false;
        }
    }
    true
}
```